# Dependencies conflict - the Foreman update

Tags: rubygems, updates, theforeman

I'm trying to update Foreman form version 1.11 to the latest 1.15. Upgrading across more than one version is not supported so I've done update version by version. Foreman 1.14 works fine and trying to update to version 1.15 I've met a problem with dependencies. Package foreman.noarch 0:1.15.2-1.el7 requires package tfm-rubygem-audited-4.4.1-1.el7.noarch, but when I try to install it I get an error:

```
Error: Package: tfm-rubygem-audited-activerecord-4.2.0-2.el7.noarch (@/tfm-rubygem-audited-activerecord-4.2.0-2.el7.noarch)
           Requires: tfm-rubygem(audited) = 4.2.0
           Removing: tfm-rubygem-audited-4.2.0-1.el7.noarch (@/tfm-rubygem-audited-4.2.0-1.el7.noarch)
               tfm-rubygem(audited) = 4.2.0
           Updated By: tfm-rubygem-audited-4.4.1-1.el7.noarch (/tfm-rubygem-audited-4.4.1-1.el7.noarch)
               tfm-rubygem(audited) = 4.4.1
```

Trying to remove tfm-rubygem-audited-activerecord-4.2.0-2.el7.noarch, because it is not required by foreman 1.15 package I get

```
error: Failed dependencies:
        tfm-rubygem(audited-activerecord) >= 4.0 is needed by (installed) foreman-1.14.3-1.el7.noarch
        tfm-rubygem(audited-activerecord) < 5.0 is needed by (installed) foreman-1.14.3-1.el7.noarch
```

Using --skip-broken with the yum does not take an effect. Is it any possiblity to resolve this conflict? The system is RHEL 7, cannot use remote repository to update foreman automatically. What is more there is no heigher version of audited-activerecord rubygem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found solution. The Foreman v.1.15 does not require any tfm-rubygem-audited-activerecord-4.2.0-2.el7.noarch. I've removed it by forcing: rpm -e --nodeps tfm-rubygem-audited-activerecord-4.2.0-2.el7.noarch and it helped, new 1.15 version od Foreman wokrs fine.